How to implement disjoint set union find in Abinitio



Unique id
person 1
person 2




1
Alan
Wake


2
Wake
Jade


3
Jack
Sparrow



In Ab-initio, I have above dataset I want to create output of 2 disjoint sets as below:



Unique id
person 1
person 2
linked people




1
Alan
Wake
Alan-Wake-Jade


2
Wake
Jade
Alan-Wake-Jade


3
Jack
Sparrow
Jack-Sparrow



These linked people could be at max 15-16 people but no of unique id are in millions how to process this efficiently in Ab-initio, I can run in 4 way parallelism.
I tried to iterate by creating global parameter of vector and added each people name in vector then created same in output, in next reformat kept on incrementing this vector till i could not find anymore
